# Agregar dados com datas diferentes e considerando outras colunas no R

Tags: r

Gostaria de agregar as linhas do `dataframe` `TBCG2`, quando a `DATA_INGRESSO_ORGAO` é diferente (vejam a coluna `ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL` números `977, 1089, 1365, 1666, 2597, 2779` e `3036`). Desejo manter a data mais antiga, conforme código abaixo. Porém, no caso da `ID 2789`, tenho `CARGOs` diferente para datas diferentes, nesse caso, quero manter as duas linhas, modificando o `ID` de uma delas acrescentando um x no `ID`. Ou seja, quero manter uma `ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL=2789` e outra `ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL=2789x`. Este dataframe é só uma parte do meu banco de dados. Como devo proceder?

```
url=url("https://raw.githack.com/fsbmat/salarioDocente/master/Teste/TBCG2.csv")
TBCG2 <- read.csv2(url, header = TRUE,encoding = "ASCII")
TBCG2$DATA_INGRESSO_ORGAO <- as.Date(as.character(TBCG2$DATA_INGRESSO_ORGAO), format = "%d/%m/%Y")
library(sqldf)
TBCG2 <- sqldf('select ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL,NOME,CPF,CARGO,
                min(DATA_INGRESSO_ORGAO) as DATA_INGRESSO_ORGAO,
                sum(BRU_Jan2013 )   as  BRU_Jan2013,        
                sum(BRU_Fev2013 )   as  BRU_Fev2013,         
                sum(BRU_Mar2013 )   as  BRU_Mar2013
                from TBCG2 
                group by ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL,NOME,CPF')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente consegui uma solução, talvez não seja a mais rápida devido ao loop, mas o importante é que deu certo. Segue o código:

```
url=url("https://raw.githack.com/fsbmat/salarioDocente/master/Teste/TBCG2.csv")
TBCG2 <- read.csv2(url, header = TRUE,encoding = "ASCII")
TBCG2$DATA_INGRESSO_ORGAO <- as.Date(as.character(TBCG2$DATA_INGRESSO_ORGAO), format = "%d/%m/%Y")
a <- c(NULL)
b <- c(NULL)
df <- TBCG2[duplicated(TBCG2$ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL),]
ID <- df$ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL
for (i in 1:length(ID)) {
  a[i] <- min((1:nrow(TBCG2))[TBCG2$ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL==ID[i]])
  b[i] <- max((1:nrow(TBCG2))[TBCG2$ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL==ID[i]])
  TBCG2$ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL[a[i]] <- ifelse(TBCG2$ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL[a[i]]==TBCG2$ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL[b[i]]&TBCG2$CARGO[a[i]]==TBCG2$CARGO[b[i]],TBCG2$ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL[a[i]],as.numeric(paste(TBCG2$ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL[a[i]],"001",sep="")))
}
library(sqldf)
TBCG2 <- sqldf('select ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL,NOME,CPF,CARGO,
                min(DATA_INGRESSO_ORGAO) as DATA_INGRESSO_ORGAO,
                sum(BRU_Jan2013 )   as  BRU_Jan2013,        
                sum(BRU_Fev2013 )   as  BRU_Fev2013,         
                sum(BRU_Mar2013 )   as  BRU_Mar2013
                from TBCG2 
                group by ID_SERVIDOR_PORTAL,NOME,CPF')
```